Why is F = ma and not mv?
Ok!  I had this same question and found the answer here at this site.  Though, physicist really seem to have a hard time explaining things in laymen’s terms. For physics beginners like myself, and because the acceleration (change in speed) confuses beginners, I found it helpful to think of the equation in reverse - ma = F. If some mass (m) is accelerating in a frictionless world, then some force (F) must be acting on the object. That force may be constant or accelerating. If it decelerates then the object continues to move on at a constant speed but with no F. It now just has momentum i.e. mass times velocity. So, in theory, if that object now hits u in the head, it’s the momentum that hurts, not the force. Physicists?  Did I get that right?

That force may be constant or accelerating. What is an “accelerating force”?

Why is F = ma and not mv? Because one agrees with experiments and the other doesn’t. Aristotle was wrong about velocity requiring force.

"I found it helpful to think of the equation in reverse." That suggests that you are thinking of $F=mA$ as if it were an assignment statement in a computer language—as if it were a directive to calculate the value of $mA$ and assign it to $F$. But that's not what "=" means in math. The "=" sign in an equation asserts that the expression on its left and the expression on its right both have the same value. If $F$ is the same thing as $mA$, then it should come as no surprise that $mA$ is the same thing as $F$.

no, you don't have it right. If a ball ($m$) has momentum $\vec p_i$ hits you in the head, that collision takes time $\Delta t$. If the ball bounces away with momentum $\vec p_f$, then the momentum change is:
$$ \Delta \vec p = \vec p_f - \vec p_i $$
which is caused by an average force acting over time:
$$ \bar F\Delta t = \Delta \vec p $$
so that:
$$ \bar F= \frac{\Delta \vec p}{\Delta t} $$
so the force hurts.
Note that:
$$ \frac 1 m \bar F = \frac{\Delta \vec p}{m\Delta t}$$
$$= \frac{m\vec v_f-m\vec v_i}{\Delta t} = \bar a $$
is an average acceleration.

I think I love this site,…get all the equations,…sort of.  Beginner here, but my point is, the object has no force at the moment just befor it impacts my head. Your force equations and damage to my head arise at impact. Otherwise the object continues on with m forever. No?

A good idea is to think of forces as arising from interactions between objects. So saying "the object has no force at the moment (...)" is not a helpful way to think about things. Either something else was acting with a force on the object, or it wasn't. But as you say, as the object comes into contact with the head, forces will arise (on the object and on the head) because the two things are now interacting.


So, in theory, if that object now hits u in the head, it’s the momentum that hurts, not the force. Physicists? Did I get that right?

No. What causes injuries is not a simple matter. However it is clearly not simply momentum that hurts. If that were so then the person firing a firearm would be hurt worse than the target.
